# Height 100% of html element safari iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

Im trying to make height of html element equal to viewport height:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/js.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

So that is all my html and css.

To take height I use js:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    alert(window.innerHeight);
    alert(document.documentElement.offsetHeight);
});
```

And on desktop browsers heights are equal. But on safari ipad height of viewport is 672 and height of html element is 692 px. Why? Help me please..

Comment: Why not read the documentation for innerHeight and offsetHeight, then for documentElement, and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: status bar takes 20 pixels is my guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status bar (*where `time`, `battery` etc are displayed.*) takes `20px` height. so the `692px` height of `html` is effective height of viewport + height of status bar (`20px`).

Comment: Is there a way to make html element 672 px with height 100%? To ignore height of the status bar somehow?

Comment: @SakerONE do you have horizontal scroll bar in landscape mode..?